# jquery element's place when toggeling

Tags: jquery, html

i'm building a page, which will have categories that will contain a list of pages to go with them. at first all the list are hidden, and than I click on a category and the list slides down. this is the code of the script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.menu-list').hide();
            $('.menu-title').click(function() {
                if ($(this).next().is(':not(:visible)')) {
                    $('.menu-list:visible').slideUp();
                    $(this).next().slideDown();
                }
     });
```

The script works, but the problem is when I'm clicking on a category in a column that has more categories than the other. than the last category is moving to the left and I don't want it to. Here is the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7rKX/4/

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the floats if you want to third menu float always to the right border.

This is because all menus are floated to the right. As long as they have the same height, the second menu will float beside the first. The third have nothing in this row so it will be positioned at the right side. But if the first menu slide out, there is something in the row of the third menu now. So the third menu will float beside the first.

[image: floating menu issue]

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7rKX/6/

Comment: You only have to add the `clear:both` to every second menu, stating from the first (1, 3, 5, 7, ...).

Comment: Or you could give the menu headline `position:relative` and then style the menu list with `position:absolute` so the layout won't float and the menu list will appear on top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add create two column divs (50% width, float left), and add each category to one of these. Then if one of them expands, the rest will be pushed down. Now the page reflows because all your categories are floated right, and the exact page layout in this case depends strongly on the height of your categories.

When you print your categories in php you can do something like this to divide your categories in columns first:

```
<?php
    $leftCol = array();
    $rightCol = array();

    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($categoryList); $i++){
        if($i%2 < 1){
            array_push($leftCol, $categoryList[$i];
        }else{
            array_push($rightCol, $categoryList[$i];
        }
    }
?>
```

Now you can print the contents of $leftCol and $rightCol in the proper column divs.

[Working example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7rKX/8/)

Comment: It's kind of a problem, because I'm using php to get the categories so I can't divide them to columns

Comment: How are you printing your html now?